# bjt behaviour in saturation mode

Tags: transistors, bjt, power-electronics

[image]

as the question stated, this bjt is now under saturation mode. and we have to find v1. 
thus, the answer will be somewhat like this
IC=4.8V/2kΩ=2.4mA
IB=2.4mA/50=48uA
Then, by KVL:

V1=VEB+48uA⋅50kΩ=VEB+2.4V
So, assuming VEB=0.7V(a reasonable assumption)

V1=3.1V
but as i know ic is not equal to beta times ib in saturation mode. then how can we assume ic equal to beta times ic to solve the answer in this question? 
also if in saturation mode ic remains unchanged even if you increase ib further, then is it possible that after some time ib becomes greater than ic {ib>ic(in sat. mode)}?

Comment: One common definition of saturation (check a few transistor datasheets) is that it starts at the point where beta drops to 10.

Comment: still it is not justified because beta being used here is 50.

Comment: Sure, Imagine your 2K is 1Meg, it is easy to overdrive the base, but not advised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule of Thumb is Ic/Ib can vary from 10 to 50 depending on Hfe but is de facto specified as Ic/Ib =10 at some Vce(sat) but for small currents can be used at Hfe=20 to 50 but ONLY IF hFE in linear zone is extremely high beta.  Diodes Inc perfected this and have hundreds of patents to describe their doping methods.

So safe for all temps is hFE=10 then Vce(sat) is low.

BUT since Vout is not specified, you can make any assumption you want for Vce(sat)

IF V1=5.7 then you have 5V/50k = 0.1mA and assuming Vce(sat) = small or say 0.2V then Ic=4.8V/2k ~ 2.4mA

thus your Ic/Ib=25 is close but depends on hFE being >>250 in linear region for 10% of hFE on my *Rule of Thumb.*

if you used V1=3.1V then  your assumption of Ic/Ib=2.4mA/48uA=50 and Vce(sat) would rise to some value.

My formula is compute Rce sat for 2.4mA from datasheet and call that ΔV/ΔI=Rce and use that loss as the rise in Vce during saturation where bulk resistance dominates.

Using the MMBT2907ALT3GOSTR
[image]

But if Ic was 500mA then Vce would be quite higher and and Ic/Ib must be lower

Comment: thanks for answering the first half of the question. but please do tell me, is it possible that ib become greater than ic ?

Comment: Yes but unnecessary ( No gain) and must be within spec limits  Ic/Ib=5 in large power transistors (hockey pucks) is the lowest I have seen. for high frequency high current low C.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably to find the threshold between active and saturation.

Obviously if V1 is just on a tiny bit, the device will not pass much Ic, therefore the voltage developed across the 2k resistor will be small -- the collector will sit near -5V and the emitter at 0V. 5V of Vce is plenty to keep it in active.

As you increase V1, however, you turn the device on. It begins conducting more and more, as this happens Vout rises upwards. The collector and the emitter voltage "squish" together. Eventually they reach a point where Vec ~ 0.2V
In saturation you can assume |Vce|=0.2V, so Vout = -0.2V. Right before this happens though, you still have Ib = Ic/Beta which holds.

You can write (1) Ib = (-0.7 + V1)/50k = Ic/Beta

And, (2) Ic = (-.2 + 5)/2k.

Solve for Ic in (2) and put it into (1), this will give you the edge of your active->saturation transition.

Any value of V1 larger than what you solve for will then give you a more heavily saturated device and Ib = Ic/Beta doesn't hold then.

Comment: thanks mate for the initial answer also please do tell me the answer of second part of my question. is it possible to have ib greater than ic??